# How do I fix Something went wrong in @nrwl/run-commands - Command failed: detox build -c ios.sim.retail.debug

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest, detox

I am experiencing an issue with opening an app for the first time

```
detox[12987] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: export EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64 && ENVFILE=.env.dev.detox xcodebuild -workspace ./apps/retail-mobile/ios/app.xcworkspace -scheme app -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ./apps/retail-mobile/ios/build -quiet

ERROR: Something went wrong in @nrwl/run-commands - Command failed: detox build -c ios.sim.retail.debug
```

How do I fix this?  I'm totally confused as it was working before.